# Paypal / Woocommerce - "Error Detected Your shopping cart is empty."

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have this error popping up when going through to paypal to pay for an order -

"Error Detected   Your shopping cart is empty."

On this website - http://wpaulphotos.com/

Plugins I have are backupbuddy, Yoast seo and woocommerce

This same error pops up for different products, so it's not related to a particular product.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working ok for me.  I added an item, went to checkout, filled out the form, and when I continued I was taken to PayPal where I signed in and was presented with the review and Pay button on the PayPal page.  I didn't complete the order, though, so if the error is happening after that I can't see it..??

On another note, using that basic PayPal that comes with WooCommerce sort of eliminates one of the benefits of PayPal for buyers.  Mainly, the ability to checkout without the need to fill in a form like you  have on your checkout page.

If you enable Express Checkout on your site payers can checkout straight from the cart page or just click the PayPal checkout button at the top of your checkout page and skip filling out all of that stuff.  This can improve conversion rates on your site quite a bit.

I'd recommend checking out [PayPal for Commerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/).  You can enable Express Checkout with that plugin and then disable the built in standard PayPal.  That should eliminate whatever problem you seem to be having as well as improve the checkout experience for your shoppers.